# Candlabra bulb threads exposed

Tags: electrical

I needed to replace a candlabra bulb, and went through several  all because the "newer ones" do not fully screw in. It works, but concerned with the exposed base.[image]

Comment: Probably are using the wrong base type.  While it is common to have neutral attached to the tread part, it is not positive(it can be hot/live) so can be dangerous.  That looks like a homemade lamp and might not be safe even with the right light in it.  Just because it works, does not mean it is right.

Comment: I should have used "not always the case" instead of "not positive".  Hope it sounds better.

Comment: this is why plugs are polarized. it shouldn't much matter in daily operation.

Comment: @dandavis if a polarized plug is bringing hot to the shell of the bulb base (instead of the neutral) because someone wired a homemade lamp backwards then it could matter quite a bit. OTOH, if the bulb base is wired _properly_ then it's less likely to be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

[![

---

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i31WD.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i31WD.png)Wrap a fitted strip of electrical tape around the threads. Some of those bulbs have a clear plastic/silicone material that is hard to see around the base and near the top of the threads, however, in your case the threads do appear to be exposed.

Comment: What type of base can I get to replace this so that I can use a led bulb?

Comment: I have seen those long candelabra bases in the store not sure what their application is. However, they also have the shorter bases that’s the ones I buy because they fit perfectly